# Has anyone ever had a company perform a "background check" that included a drug test without mentioning the drug test explicitly?

Tags: background-check, drug-test

I am applying for a job at a non-profit that is federally funded. I was told I needed to pass a background check before getting hired.  I have already begun the background check process and there has been no mention of a drug test yet (besides me granting them access to results of any past drug tests). Could they still ask me to take one without notifying me? How far in advance are applicants typically told before they are required to submit to testing? Has anyone has ever done a background check where they didn't mention you needed a drug test then suddenly did?

Comment: *I have already begun the background check process...* Assuming this means that you're far along in the hiring process, you can ask for the employee handbook. That would probably tell you whether they do drug testing.

Answer (score 7):

> Has anyone has ever done a background check where they didn't mention you needed a drug test then suddenly did?

Not in my experience. Some employers require a background check, some require a drug screen, and some require both. Employers generally tell you up front, immediately, everything that's required of as part of their process.

> Could they still ask me to take [a drug test] without notifying me?

Sure, but it's unlikely. It would be a waste of the employer's time to go through a background check and then "surprise" you with a drug test. In any event, you would have to consent to such a test, and would have the option of withdrawing your application.

If they have not mentioned a drug test, then it's probably not something they do.

Answer (score 4):

You should always assume a drug test is coming when you are looking for employment.

Even though every last employer knows that they probably won't catch anyone, the sentiment is that if you cannot stay off drugs while looking for employment, you have a problem.

Of course they can do it, it's not likely, as they usually inform you WAAAAAY ahead (as in long enough to get it out of your system) go with the assumption that it's coming and don't ruin your chances.